# Displaying value of a variable in Jscript in MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing MVC app.
In the view, I have declare some variable and I want to use it in the Jscript.

```
    @model PaymentAdviceEntity.EMI
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Create";
        double TotalAmt = 0;

    }


    @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "EMI", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "frmEdit" }))
    {
      @if (Model.EMI_Child.Count > 0)
     {
      @foreach (var PaidEMIList in Model.EMI_Child)
       {           
        TotalAmt = TotalAmt + PaidEMIList.Amount;
       }
     }              
   }


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        CheckBalAmt();
     });

  function CheckBalAmt()
{

    var nTotalAmount = document.getElementById("TotalAmount").value;      
    var nAllreadyPaidAmount = document.getElementById("AllreadyPaidAmount").value;    
    var BalAmt = nTotalAmount - nAllreadyPaidAmount;
    var totalAmt1 = @TotalAmt; <- Shows error here...
    var BalAndTotalAmt  = BalAmt +totalAmt1; 
   $('.BalanceAmt').text("Bal Amt. : " +  BalAndTotalAmt );
}

</script>
```

in above CheckBalAmt() method I want to show the value of variable TotalAmt ...
but it dont show anything...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    function CheckBalAmt()
    {

       alert('@TotalAmt');

    }
```

You have to use the razor symbol

Comment: Thanks it works...and what if I have to use in some statement ?   `var BalAndTotalAmt  = BalAmt + $('@TotalAmt');` is that correct ?

Comment: Do something like: var total = @TotalAmt; Then do var BalAndTotalAmt = BalAmt + total;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34347/discussion-between-user1650894-and-tgh)

Answer (score 0):

```
var totalAmt1 = ('@TotalAmt');
var BalAndTotalAmt  = BalAmt - totalAmt1;
alert(@TotalAmt);
$('.BalanceAmt').text("Bal Amt. : " +  BalAndTotalAmt );
```

this code works...